# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load [netty-tcnative-linux-x86_64, netty-tcnative-linux-x86_64-fedora, netty-tcnative]

Tags: java, tomcat, netty

I'm using https://github.com/lafaspot/imapnio

in a tomcat based java server. The imapnio library uses netty internally to execute imap commands in a non-blocking way.

I get the following exception when I try to do a IMAPClient.createSession()

```
> Unable to load the library: netty-tcnative-linux-x86_64.
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Load library failed!
    at** io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:261)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:250)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:242)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:194)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:166)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.loadTcNative(OpenSsl.java:380)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:99)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultProvider(SslContext.java:115)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultClientProvider(SslContext.java:111)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newClientContextInternal(SslContext.java:745)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:397)
    at com.lafaspot.imapnio.client.IMAPSession.<init>(IMAPSession.java:135)
    at com.lafaspot.imapnio.client.IMAPClient.createSession(IMAPClient.java:68)
    at com.try.platform.imap.work.IMAPMailboxWork.<init>(IMAPMailboxWork.java:58)
    at com.try.platform.imap.pollers.IMAPPoller.initiateIMAPPoller(IMAPPoller.java:144)
    at com.try.platform.imap.pollers.IMAPService.initiateIMAPServices(IMAPService.java:14)
    at com.try.common.AppLoader.initiateAllWorkers(AppLoader.java:64)
    at com.try.common.AppLoader.contextInitialized(AppLoader.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:259)
    .. 27 more
**Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty-tcnative-linux-x86_64 in java.library.path**
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
    .. 32 more
Unable to load the library: netty-tcnative-linux-x86_64.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty-tcnative-linux-x86_64 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:245)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:194)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:166)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.loadTcNative(OpenSsl.java:380)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:99)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultProvider(SslContext.java:115)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultClientProvider(SslContext.java:111)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newClientContextInternal(SslContext.java:745)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:397)
    at com.lafaspot.imapnio.client.IMAPSession.<init>(IMAPSession.java:135)
    at com.lafaspot.imapnio.client.IMAPClient.createSession(IMAPClient.java:68)
    at com.try.platform.imap.work.IMAPMailboxWork.<init>(IMAPMailboxWork.java:58)
    at com.try.platform.imap.pollers.IMAPPoller.initiateIMAPPoller(IMAPPoller.java:144)
    at com.try.platform.imap.pollers.IMAPService.initiateIMAPServices(IMAPService.java:14)
    at com.try.common.AppLoader.initiateAllWorkers(AppLoader.java:64)
    at com.try.common.AppLoader.contextInitialized(AppLoader.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Unable to load the library: netty-tcnative-linux-x86_64-fedora.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Load library failed!
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:261)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:250)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:242)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:194)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:166)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.loadTcNative(OpenSsl.java:380)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:99)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultProvider(SslContext.java:115)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultClientProvider(SslContext.java:111)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newClientContextInternal(SslContext.java:745)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:397)
    at com.lafaspot.imapnio.client.IMAPSession.<init>(IMAPSession.java:135)
    at com.lafaspot.imapnio.client.IMAPClient.createSession(IMAPClient.java:68)
    at com.try.platform.imap.work.IMAPMailboxWork.<init>(IMAPMailboxWork.java:58)
    at com.try.platform.imap.pollers.IMAPPoller.initiateIMAPPoller(IMAPPoller.java:144)
    at com.try.platform.imap.pollers.IMAPService.initiateIMAPServices(IMAPService.java:14)
    at com.try.common.AppLoader.initiateAllWorkers(AppLoader.java:64)
    at com.try.common.AppLoader.contextInitialized(AppLoader.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:259)
    .. 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty-tcnative-linux-x86_64-fedora in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
    .. 32 more
Unable to load the library: netty-tcnative-linux-x86_64-fedora.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty-tcnative-linux-x86_64-fedora in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:245)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:194)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:166)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.loadTcNative(OpenSsl.java:380)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:99)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultProvider(SslContext.java:115)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultClientProvider(SslContext.java:111)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newClientContextInternal(SslContext.java:745)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:397)
    at com.lafaspot.imapnio.client.IMAPSession.<init>(IMAPSession.java:135)
    at com.lafaspot.imapnio.client.IMAPClient.createSession(IMAPClient.java:68)
    at com.try.platform.imap.work.IMAPMailboxWork.<init>(IMAPMailboxWork.java:58)
    at com.try.platform.imap.pollers.IMAPPoller.initiateIMAPPoller(IMAPPoller.java:144)
    at com.try.platform.imap.pollers.IMAPService.initiateIMAPServices(IMAPService.java:14)
    at com.try.common.AppLoader.initiateAllWorkers(AppLoader.java:64)
    at com.try.common.AppLoader.contextInitialized(AppLoader.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Unable to load the library: netty-tcnative.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Load library failed!
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:261)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibraryByHelper(NativeLibraryLoader.java:250)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:242)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:194)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:166)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.loadTcNative(OpenSsl.java:380)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:99)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultProvider(SslContext.java:115)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultClientProvider(SslContext.java:111)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newClientContextInternal(SslContext.java:745)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:397)
    at com.lafaspot.imapnio.client.IMAPSession.<init>(IMAPSession.java:135)
    at com.lafaspot.imapnio.client.IMAPClient.createSession(IMAPClient.java:68)
    at com.try.platform.imap.work.IMAPMailboxWork.<init>(IMAPMailboxWork.java:58)
    at com.try.platform.imap.pollers.IMAPPoller.initiateIMAPPoller(IMAPPoller.java:144)
    at com.try.platform.imap.pollers.IMAPService.initiateIMAPServices(IMAPService.java:14)
    at com.try.common.AppLoader.initiateAllWorkers(AppLoader.java:64)
    at com.try.common.AppLoader.contextInitialized(AppLoader.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader$1.run(NativeLibraryLoader.java:259)
    .. 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty-tcnative in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
    .. 32 more
Unable to load the library: netty-tcnative.
**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no netty-tcnative in java.library.path**
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryUtil.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryUtil.java:38)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:245)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.load(NativeLibraryLoader.java:194)
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:166)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.loadTcNative(OpenSsl.java:380)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:99)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultProvider(SslContext.java:115)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultClientProvider(SslContext.java:111)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newClientContextInternal(SslContext.java:745)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:397)
    at com.lafaspot.imapnio.client.IMAPSession.<init>(IMAPSession.java:135)
    at com.lafaspot.imapnio.client.IMAPClient.createSession(IMAPClient.java:68)
    at com.try.platform.imap.work.IMAPMailboxWork.<init>(IMAPMailboxWork.java:58)
    at com.try.platform.imap.pollers.IMAPPoller.initiateIMAPPoller(IMAPPoller.java:144)
    at com.try.platform.imap.pollers.IMAPService.initiateIMAPServices(IMAPService.java:14)
    at com.try.common.AppLoader.initiateAllWorkers(AppLoader.java:64)
    at com.try.common.AppLoader.contextInitialized(AppLoader.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Failed to load netty-tcnative; OpenSslEngine will be unavailable, unless the application has already loaded the symbols by some other means. See http://netty.io/wiki/forked-tomcat-native.html for more information.
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to load any of the given libraries: [netty-tcnative-linux-x86_64, netty-tcnative-linux-x86_64-fedora, netty-tcnative]**
    at io.netty.util.internal.NativeLibraryLoader.loadFirstAvailable(NativeLibraryLoader.java:172)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.loadTcNative(OpenSsl.java:380)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:99)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultProvider(SslContext.java:115)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultClientProvider(SslContext.java:111)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newClientContextInternal(SslContext.java:745)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:397)
    at com.lafaspot.imapnio.client.IMAPSession.<init>(IMAPSession.java:135)
    at com.lafaspot.imapnio.client.IMAPClient.createSession(IMAPClient.java:68)
    at com.try.platform.imap.work.IMAPMailboxWork.<init>(IMAPMailboxWork.java:58)
    at com.try.platform.imap.pollers.IMAPPoller.initiateIMAPPoller(IMAPPoller.java:144)
    at com.try.platform.imap.pollers.IMAPService.initiateIMAPServices(IMAPService.java:14)
    at com.try.common.AppLoader.initiateAllWorkers(AppLoader.java:64)
    at com.try.common.AppLoader.contextInitialized(AppLoader.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Failed to initialize netty-tcnative; OpenSslEngine will be unavailable.  for more information.
**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no provided in java.library.path**
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.<init>(Library.java:80)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.initialize(Library.java:180)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.initializeTcNative(OpenSsl.java:385)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl.<clinit>(OpenSsl.java:110)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultProvider(SslContext.java:115)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.defaultClientProvider(SslContext.java:111)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContext.newClientContextInternal(SslContext.java:745)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslContextBuilder.build(SslContextBuilder.java:397)
    at com.lafaspot.imapnio.client.IMAPSession.<init>(IMAPSession.java:135)
    at com.lafaspot.imapnio.client.IMAPClient.createSession(IMAPClient.java:68)
    at com.try.platform.imap.work.IMAPMailboxWork.<init>(IMAPMailboxWork.java:58)
    at com.try.platform.imap.pollers.IMAPPoller.initiateIMAPPoller(IMAPPoller.java:144)
    at com.try.platform.imap.pollers.IMAPService.initiateIMAPServices(IMAPService.java:14)
    at com.try.common.AppLoader.initiateAllWorkers(AppLoader.java:64)
    at com.try.common.AppLoader.contextInitialized(AppLoader.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The system is unable to find the netty-tcnative series of libraries.
It works with out the above exceptions on a mac machine. But throws this above exception on a Linux Machine. (Amazon AMI Linux EC2 instance)

The machine is unable to find netty-tcnative-linux-x86_64, netty-tcnative and netty-tcnative-linux-x86_64-fedora jars even though I have explicitly added these in pom.xml

Can you please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check upgrading to netty-tcnative (2.0.7). I was facing the same issue upgrading to 2.0.x might help. [Failed to load any of the given libraries: [netty-tcnative-linux-x86_64,netty-tcnative]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50014276/failed-to-load-any-of-the-given-libraries-netty-tcnative-linux-x86-64-netty-tc)

Check this for the full list of version which i used.

2. Or if upgrading is not possible, libtcnative-1.so.0.2.16 download this rpm and try exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH and -Djava.library.path (pass this as CATALINA_OPTS) to the directory of the .so file